# PHP ibm_db2 how to change CONN_CODEPAGE to 1208

Tags: php, character-encoding, db2

I have a db2 database with this charset options:

```
db2 get db cfg for CORRETGE
    Database territory       = US
    Database code page       = 1208
    Database code set        = UTF-8
```

But when I connect to the database from a PHP 5.4.1.RC1 script with [db2_connect()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.db2-connect.php), I get this CONN_CODEPAGE:

```
public 'APPL_CODEPAGE' => int 819
public 'CONN_CODEPAGE' => int 819
```

Database has 1208 (UTF-8 encoding of Unicode) codepage and the connection has 819 (ISO8859-1) codepage, and this provoque charset problems.

I don't know how to set 1208 as the CONN_CODEPAGE. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED**

Set the [DB2CODEPAGE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.sql.doc/doc/c0006825.htm&resultof=%22db2codepage%22%20%22db2codepag%22%20) variable to 1208 with the command

```
  db2set DB2CODEPAGE=1208
```

and restart DB2

now db2_client_info() returns

```
public 'APPL_CODEPAGE' => int 1208
public 'CONN_CODEPAGE' => int 1208
```

and the results are the expected :)

Comment: Just a note: `DB2CODEPAGE` is a client-level parameter, and it sounds like you set it on your server.  This is fine if your web server is running on the same machine as DB2, but if you were to move the web server to a separate machine the setting on the database server would no longer apply.

Comment: Yes, DB2 and Apache are in the same machine. Thanks